# ValueError buffer source array is read-only

Tags: python, scikit-image, glcm

I'm using this code to extract GLCM features for a certain image but it gives me a value error

**Code:**

```py
from PIL import Image
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
fname = 'trial.jpg'
img = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
img = img.resize((224, 224))
test_glcm = greycomatrix(img, [1], [np.pi/2], 256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```

**Error:**

> ValueError buffer source array is read-only

Does anyone knows what that means, or what may be the problem in the code?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the error you just need to convert the PIL image into a NumPy array like this:

```py
test_glcm = greycomatrix(np.array(img), [1], [np.pi/2], 256, symmetric=True, normed=True)
```